# Angular - On Paste Event Get Content

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular component that allows a user to enter data into a `textarea`. There are two events tied to this `keydown` and `paste`. Both of these events trigger the same method which will try and determine the data entered.

The issue I am having is when the data is pasted `paste`, I am getting the value of the `formControl` but its the value BEFORE the data is pasted and doesn't include what I actually just entered into the field.

**HTML**

```
<textarea 
  formControlName="multiSearch" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Enter one or more values. One per line." 
  rows="6" 
  (keydown)="keyDownFunction($event)"
  (paste)="onPaste()">
</textarea>
```

**Component**

```
  /**
   * If we hit enter in our text area, determine the data type
   */
  keyDownFunction(event) {

    // Enter Key?
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      this.determineDataType();
    }
  }

  /**
   * If we paste data in our text area, determine the data type
   */
  onPaste() {
    this.determineDataType();
  }

  /**
   * Using regex, determine the datatype of the data and confirm with the user.
   */
  determineDataType() {
    console.log(this.searchForm.value.multiSearch)
  }
```

**Question**
How can I get access to the data that is pasted into the form as soon as the `paste` event is fired and not what the value was before pasting?

Comment: Did you try using `[(ngModel)]` as attribute in text area element? 
[ngModel doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get the pasted content from the `paste` event and the updated content of the `textarea` by handling the `input` event:

```
<textarea #myText (paste)="onPaste($event)" (input)="onInput(myText.value)"></textarea>
```

with this code:

```
onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
  let clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
  ...
}

onInput(content: string) {
  ...
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4gi6n) for a demo.

Comment: ClipboardEvent not supported in iexplorer 11

Comment: Any clue why I can't PASTE on an empty input after add (paste)="doSomething()" ? I can paste if I have any char there, but if it's empty, paste doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

This is from an example with angular2 typescript that works for my project. Hope it helps someone. Logic is same for other cases as-well.

1. angular-clipboard-event.html

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type a message" (paste)="onPaste($event)"></textarea>
<!-- Place to render the image -->
<img #imgRenderer />
```

2. angular-clipboard-event.ts

```js
// Reference to the dom element
@ViewChild('imgRenderer') imgRenderer: ElementRef;

onPaste(event: any) {
    const items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    let blob = null;

    for (const item of items) {
      if (item.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        blob = item.getAsFile();
      }
    }

    // load image if there is a pasted image
    if (blob !== null) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (evt: any) => {
        console.log(evt.target.result); // data url!
        this.imgRenderer.nativeElement.src = evt.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep, instead of Ctrl + V for pasting,  have any method or code to handle from UI?