# Angular paste from clipboard

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a chance to implement a paste button in Angular.

FE: User copies a link of the website and on my page when he or she hits a button copied link should appear in a textbox.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138910/angular-on-paste-event-get-content

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only copy from a webpage programmatically. You cannot programmatically paste anything because this is a security violation. However, you can add

```
(paste)="onPaste($event)"
```

to get the pasted clipboard details from control + v

Answer (score 3):

Now is possible to read Clipboard from the new Clipboard Api like this:

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
      text => {
        yourVariable = text;
      }
     )
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Cannot read clipboard text: ', error);
      }
    );
```

A popup will appear asking to the user if they want to allow this operation.