# Need angular 2+ 'number only' directive that uses type as number, regex and allows copy paste

Tags: regex, angular, angular-directive

I have an input type number. I have a directive that successfully blocks characters other than numbers. And this also allows only single decimal point.

What I need is, the directive should allow copy from field and paste into the field as well.

```
<input type="number" appNumbersOnly />
```

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appNumbersOnly]'
  })
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
    public text;
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab'];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) return;

      const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      const next: string = current.concat(event.key);

      if(next.includes('.')){
        if(this.text == next) event.preventDefault();
        this.text= next;
      }
      if ((next && !String(next).match(this.regex))) {  
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
```

How to make this directive allow copy paste?

Comment: Have you tried using 'change' instead of 'keypress' ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please follow the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid getting downvoted. It is good that you tried yourself, but edit your question so that you explain further the context and why you did, what you did.

Comment: @xdecdec 'change' event and 'input' event are triggered after "type="text"" modifies the inut value. For example, if I type double dot(..), "type="text"" makes the value of input as blank('') internally. So, the event triggered by 'change' or 'input' will have '' as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your requirenment. But I think this can help you.

copy
[Angular 5 - Copy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49102724/angular-5-copy-to-clipboard)

Paste
[Angular - On Paste Event Get Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138910/angular-on-paste-event-get-content)