# Search not working on keydown event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code

```
  <input [(ngModel)]="search.Name" type="text" class="form-control" (keydown)="search()" 
  maxlength="40" placeholder="Search">
```

when i change the data in textfield then it is working but when i copy paste the value in textfield it does not show any record, copy paste is not working with `keydown` event

I have tried with `(ngModelChange)` but the same issue.

Comment: Handle the `paste` event - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138910/angular-on-paste-event-get-content

Comment: @briosheje Will calling `search()` function on `paste` event work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Input" event instead of "keydown"

```
<input [(ngModel)]="search.Name" type="text" class="form-control" (input)="search()" maxlength="40" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: Thanks but getting same issue i have to click on text field to get desired result after `paste` event